# Ubuntu: How to send a "close" command to a window with a title matching a regex?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, window-manager

I need to programatically close a window in some program, based on the window title.

Is there a tool or a built-in system command I can use for that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`wmctrl` can close a window based on a substring or exact match of the window title (`wmctrl -c 'substring'` or `wmctrl -F -c 'exact match'`).

If you need more control, you can parse `wmctrl -l`, extract the matching window IDs and pass them to `wmctrl -i -c`. You can use `wmctrl -x -l` and match the class as well; in fact, I recommend it, since applications you haven't thought about might have windows with the same title.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, when I'm connected via ssh wmctrl returns "Cannot open display". Is there a way around that?

Comment: @GJ: Programs normally connect to the display indicated by the `DISPLAY` environment variable. If you're connected via `ssh` and have X forwarding enabled, `wmctrl` acts on *your* display; without X forwarding `DISPLAY` won't be set. You'll also have to provide the *cookie*: that's a password that's generated when you log in and stored in the file indicated in the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable. [Read this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596), and if you still can't figure it out, ask another question on acting remotely over an X display.